# OpenURI 403 Error on Heroku, Ruby on Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, http-status-code-403, open-uri

I'm using Rails 4 with Ruby 2, deployed on Heroku. My application uses OpenURI to open a Webpage (then passes the HTML to Nokogiri for parsing). On my local machine this works fine; on Heroku, I receive a 403 Error when the program arrives at the line with the `open` method. I have already done the following:

- Required `open-uri` in my application
- Added the `'User-Agent'` key to my `open` method call
- Included all required Heroku compatibility gems in my Gemfile as specified [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4#heroku-gems)

Here's the offending line:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url, 'User-Agent' => "Ruby/#{RUBY_VERSION}"))
```

Here are the relevant (I believe) Heroku logs:

```
2013-10-22T01:20:53.281117+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/texts/parse" for 66.
31.247.63 at 2013-10-22 01:20:53 +0000
2013-10-22T01:20:53.281117+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/texts/parse" for 66.
31.247.63 at 2013-10-22 01:20:53 +0000
2013-10-22T01:20:53.287518+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by TextsController#parse
 as HTML
2013-10-22T01:20:53.287518+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by TextsController#parse
 as HTML
2013-10-22T01:20:53.287692+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"???", "auth
enticity_token"=>"zKqzrI7qaDjav1HA56kdiNi01Mgbavg4Xhff+t4bDh0=", "url"=>"http://
www.gutenberg.org/files/135/135-h/135-h.htm", "commit"=>"Import"}
2013-10-22T01:20:53.287692+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"???", "auth
enticity_token"=>"zKqzrI7qaDjav1HA56kdiNi01Mgbavg4Xhff+t4bDh0=", "url"=>"http://
www.gutenberg.org/files/135/135-h/135-h.htm", "commit"=>"Import"}
2013-10-22T01:20:44.346845+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `b
in/rails server -p 30331 -e $RAILS_ENV`
2013-10-22T01:20:53.536799+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error
 in 247ms
2013-10-22T01:20:53.536799+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error
 in 247ms
2013-10-22T01:20:53.537796+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-10-22T01:20:53.537796+00:00 app[web.1]: OpenURI::HTTPError (403 Forbidden):

2013-10-22T01:20:53.537796+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/texts_controller.
rb:75:in `parse'
2013-10-22T01:20:53.537796+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-10-22T01:20:53.537796+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-10-22T01:20:53.537796+00:00 app[web.1]:
2013-10-22T01:20:53.537796+00:00 app[web.1]: OpenURI::HTTPError (403 Forbidden):

2013-10-22T01:20:53.537796+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/texts_controller.
rb:75:in `parse'
```

I've done a lot of searching and can't find a fix. Usually the problem is that people forget to require `'open-uri'` in their application. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I should also add that I investigated the default encoding of my application, and in my Heroku console it claims the application encodes in UTF-8 by default.

Comment: Have you tried the commands from the heroku rails console?